# converting base64 to image property in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting a base64 image from ASP.Net local server and read it as a property in my class

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *ImageName;
```

I want to convert the read base64 into an image and display it in my method

```
marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:"display it here"];
marker.map = mapView_;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code. It may help you.

```
NSString *string64 = //... some string base 64 encoded

//convert your string to data

NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:string64   options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];

UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

Answer (score 0):

Encoding data:-

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:"mypic"]; , 0.5);
NSString* strImageData1 = [Base64 encode:imageData];
```

Decode Data:-

`NSString *strImage=strImageData1;
 NSData* data = [Base64 decode:strImage];
imageObja.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];`

Answer (score 0):

Download 2 files .h and .m and add those in your project from: https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64/tree/master/Base64

I did this in one of my project and it is working well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

While saving:

```
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];
```

While Reading:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:string options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
[UIImage imageWithData:data];
```